# Optional function parameter based value of template parameter

Tags: c++, templates

So I understand I could probably solve this problem by simply using a parameter pack, but that solution seems a little ugly to me. What I want to do is something like the following:

```
template<bool test>
void Foo(int x, int y, int z, /*if test is set to true*/ int w)
{
   if constexpr(test)
   {
     //use w for something.
   }
}
```

So basically use the template parameter to say whether the last parameter is required or not. If test is false and an argument is passed in for w then there should be a compilation error saying too many arguments were provided. Any ideas what is available to me to achieve something like this elegantly?

Comment: I'd argue overloading is a better use-case for this.

Comment: I would suggest removing the template and just having two overloads.  You can also move the common logic into a helper function that each overload can call to keep the code DRY.

Comment: Yeah, overloading is definitely an option, I was just hoping there'd be something nice and convenient in the standard library :)

Comment: If you didn't want a compiler error, you could just add a default value to `w` and call it done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might decouple interface from implementation, use overloads and `enable_if`:

```
namespace detail
{
    struct Empty {};

    template<typename T>
    void FooImpl(int x,int y, int z, T w)
    {
        constexpr test = std::is_same_v<T, Empty>;
        if constexpr(test)
        {
            //use w for something
        }
    }
}

template<bool test>
std::enable_if_t<test> void Foo(int x, int y, int z, int w)
{
   detail::FooImpl(x, y, z, w);
}

template<bool test>
std::enable_if_t<!test> void Foo(int x, int y, int z)
{
   detail::FooImpl(x, y, z, detail::Empty{});
}
```

Note that in the generic case, you’d likely use `std::forward<>` on the interface and perhaps document (using a `static_assert()`) that the type of `w` is `Empty` or `int`.

Answer (score 0):

I think templates are the wrong tool for the job here. Instead you can use [`std::optional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional) to do what you're looking for:

```
#include <optional>

void Foo(int x, int y, int z, std::optional<int> w=std::nullopt) {
    if (w) {
      // use (*w) for something.
    }
}

int main() {
    Foo(1, 2, 3);
    Foo(1, 2, 3, 100);
}
```

Comment: Instead of writing out default argument `=std::optional<int>()`, you could write `=std::nullopt` for the same effect.

Comment: @aschepler Excellent suggestion